# How to create custom report in java melody?

Tags: java, monitoring, java-melody

I want to track some specific servlet requests.
Is it possible to create custom reports for particular requests and monitor it with Java Melody?

Also, to create one sample custom report,
I tried to implement as per the example given in "Custom Report" section from below link,
https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#custom-reports.
i.e added parameter "custom-reports", Created one Jsp page and provided it's path as value of this custom report.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>custom-reports</param-name>
    <param-value>customReport</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
        <param-name>customReport</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/MyCustomReport.jsp</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but not able to see any link for new custom report on the floating menu.
Also, When I tried with url to open the custom report only,
http://localhost:8080/MyTestProject/monitoring?report=customReport

I am getting below NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringController.doCustomReport(MonitoringController.java:482)
    net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringController.doReportCore(MonitoringController.java:208)
    net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringController.doReport(MonitoringController.java:186)
    net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringController.doActionIfNeededAndReport(MonitoringController.java:148)
    net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doMonitoring(MonitoringFilter.java:342)
    net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:167)
    net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:160)
```

[Note: I am working with javaMelody version 1.57.0]

**Any suggestions/help?**

Comment: The answer can be found in documentation https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#custom-reports

Comment: I tried to follow as mentioned in above link.
but not able to see any link for new custom report on the floating menu.
Also, I tried with url like below,
http://localhost:8080/MyTestProject/monitoring?graph=customReport

But getting nullpointer exception:

"java.lang.NullPointerException
 net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringController.doCustomReport(MonitoringController.java:482).."